# How to correctly capture parse Date in REST Service

Tags: javascript, vb.net, date

I have one calendar in my front end and as soon as I select one date the request should go to the REST Service at server. Currently I am able to get the date string at Server but how can I get the actual date object out of that "String" which I received as "DATE"

Below is what I have tried till now.
Date Selected at front end: 10th August 2016

Equivalent Date received as String at backend: "1470873599000"

QUESTION 1: How can I create a Date object and store this String received. Eventually I need to pass date as #8/10/2016# to my actual code from the string received. Please guide me.

QUESTION 2: OR Do I need to change the way I have sent the Date from my Javascript code.

**EDIT:**

FRONT END CODE FOR SENDING DATE: JAVASCRIPT

```
localStorage.setItem('date', start._d.getTime());  // 1470873599000
localStorage.getItem('date') // It is sent via AJAX CALL
```

The REST Service which I have written in VB.net to capture the date:

```
'getter setter for the date
    <DataMember(Name:="dateProp")>
    Private dateId As String
    Public Property dateProp() As String
        Get
            Return dateId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            dateId = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: What are you using at Front End ? FIddle is always suggested for asking any code help :)

Comment: I am already getting the date string at backend. Only issue is how to convert that string received into the actual date.

Comment: I need to convert/parse `1470873599000` to something like `#8/10/2016#`

Comment: `dt = New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).AddMilliseconds(1470873599000)`  Look up what javascript returns for `getTime` to see how it works

Comment: @pravs—far better to post code here as a runnable snippet than at some remote location that may or may not be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend changing the javascript to

```
localStorage.setItem('date', start._d.toISOString());
```

which will give a readable date/time/timezone

```
"2016-08-16T15:49:49.574Z"
```

and to parse it on the server

```
Dim myInput = "2016-08-16T15:49:49.574Z"
Dim theDate = DateTime.Parse(myInput)
```